# Categories countries into continents

Tags: r

Is there anyone who knows how to categorise the countries in my data into continents?

My data (it's called Ximputed):
[view screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5HJS.png)

I have tried to use following code but it doesn't work at all

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
Region <- ne_countries(country = Ximputed$country, returnclass = "sf")
Region <- rename.vars(Region, 'sovereignt', 'country')
x2 <- Ximputed %>% 
  left_join(Region, "country")
```

Comment: Please include a section of your data into the question pasting the output of `dput(head(Ximputed, 10))`; this makes the question reproducible, There is a spelling error: 'sovereignty'.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. I don't have your actual data, so I can't test. This also assumes that the country names are consistent.

```r
continents <- raster::ccodes() |>
  dplyr::select(country = NAME, continent)

dplyr::left_join(Ximputed, continents, by = "country")
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried usying that code but i get the following error: "error in is.data.frame(y) : object 'continent' not found" :/